# How to remove a program that isn't in dpkg or apt?

Tags: uninstall

This may be hard to diagnose because I don't know exactly everything I did, I was just trying a bunch of different things to get it to work.

**My current problem**
I have GDAL on my system, version 2.1.3 I'm trying to remove it (for reasons why, refer to my other question on [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228938/gdal-2-1-3-doesnt-have-libkml/229022?noredirect=1#comment355185_229022))

I know the program is still on my machine, because when I run `gdal-config --version` or `ogrinfo --version` I get the output of version 2.1.3.

I have tried to remove the program in the following ways:
- Delete all files and folders
- `sudo apt-get --purge remove gdal-bin`

I have looked in `dpkg --get-selections` and `apt-get list` and have also removed any program containing gdal. However, it still isn't uninstalled.

**How I installed it**
As mentioned, I have tried a few different way because I was working on configuring it a certain way, as described in my gis.stackexchange questions. I have tried following:
- Downloading from the osgeo.org website following [this stackexchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120101/building-gdal-with-libkml-support)
- Downloading it from someone's github using [this tutorial](https://github.com/kubark42/libkml)
- Using PPA following [this tutorial](http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html)

I have a feeling it has something to do with how I tried installing it the first time.

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/etc-data.koordinates.com/gdal-travisci/install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz
tar xzf install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz
sudo cp -r install-libkml/include/* /usr/local/include
sudo cp -r install-libkml/lib/* /usr/local/lib
sudo ldconfig
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.11.1/gdal-1.11.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf gdal-1.11.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-1.11.1
# Prefix is pointing to my empty directory to not mix with my other GDAL install
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gdal-compile --with-libkml
make
make install
ldconfig
export PATH=$HOME/gdal-compile/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/gdal-compile:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Because I admittingly don't know exactly everything that I did by following that.

Any ideas on how I can fully remove this program from my system?

**Update:**

As per request, I ran the following with the following output

```
$ type ogrinfo
ogrinfo is /usr/local/bin/ogrinfo

$ sudo apt remove gdal-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gdal-bin' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ gdal-config --version
2.1.3
```

**1** Output of `type orginfo`

```
ogrinfo is /usr/local/bin/ogrinfo
```

**2** How do I know it's still on my system
When I type `ogrinfo --version` it outputs `GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01` and when I type `gdal-config --version` it outputs 2.1.3 - this tells me it's still on my system, correct? Otherwise wouldn't it output something like "command not found"

**3** Outfrom from `sudo updatedb;locate -ir "/ogrinfo$"`

```
/bin/bash
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/bash
/etc/apparmor.d/snap/abstractions/bash
/usr/share/doc/bash
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bash
/usr/share/menu/bash
```

Comment: if you have the source directory (extracted from the tar archive), you may be able to uninstall by `cd`ing into the source directory, and running `sudo make uninstall`. This is not always supported though.

Comment: @Zanna Well let's assume that I'm an idiot and already deleted the folder in hopes that it would just magically uninstall itself. How would I uninstall it then?

Comment: hmm with difficulty... I'll download it myself and have a look at it shortly, but I don't know if I'll be able to make anything of it. Meanwhile, some smarter folks may show up here...

Comment: According to your Question, you installed it more than one way and may have more than one installation.  Will you run these commands and add the output to your question **(1)** `type ogrinfo` **(2)** `sudo apt remove gdal-bin`?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure I'll be able to provide you with a clean resolve.  Can you answer three  questions.  First I don't see **(1)**  the output of **`type ogrinfo`**.  It'll most likely be an error message.  **(2)** can you tell me **how you know it's still on your system**.  And **(3)** `sudo updatedb;locate -ir "/ogrinfo$"`.  There are a couple other commands I'll ask you to run based on the response of these current two question.

Comment: @L.D.James updated the requested info again. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks... sorry for the redundancy.  I see two of the commands were already in your question.  I'll be more careful to search the question for the needed info.  Can you give the output of: `dpkg -s 'ogrinfo'`

Comment: @L.D.James `dpkg-query: package 'ogrinfo' is not installed and no information is available

Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files, and pdkg --contents (= pdkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.`

Comment: @L.D.James I've been told since the files are in `/usr/local/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin/` that my system still has a self-compiled version installed. Would it be as simple as just deleting all of the gdal files in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53952/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-amallard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Removing a program that isn't installed using dpkg or apt.

**How to complete remove the installed program:**

Many program have an install intructional with a name similar to **Readme.txt** or **Install.txt** that include steps for both installing and uninstalling.  Following those provisions will usually completely remove the installation.

Most programs installed by compiling and `make install`, have a `MakeFile` **uninstall** facility (`make uninstall`).

During the `make install` there is dialog showing where the installer is doing.  This shows where the files are being copied.  You can run `make` with the `-n` argument.  This is a dry run of the installer.  Study the output of the dry run to see where the files will be placed.

**Dry install run**

Run this after the fact:

```
$ make -n install
```

Now you can see where the binaries and depends have been copied from the compile directory.  Compile the list of destinations and remove those files from the list.

Comment: I ended up just having to `locate gdal` and `rm` any and all instances found. After then there was no more residual files interfering with my fresh install of gdal from the ppa repo

Comment: I'm glad you were able to satisfactory clean out the compiled install.  I'm sure this is what you were explaining to me in chat.  I was trying to put a definitive answer to the question so that others could benefit, and of course, so that you would have surety of not having conflicting files after your subsequent install.  Hope my persistent questions wasn't an imposition.

Comment: Hi @amallard I am trying to do exactly what you did here. How did you combine `locate gdal` and `rm` into one command? As you can see I am a absolute beginner in Linux